# How to play android local media to DLNA Renderer?

Tags: android, sockets, dlna

I am trying to play android local media on DLNA renders.

I am currently able to play any global visible media on DLNA renderer which have URI starts with  http://172.168.1.1:4566/content_media/file1297834.mp3 this media is also play on any web browser, 
But when I try to play local media which have file URI like file;//storage/content/media/file.mp3; is not playing on DLNA Renderer.
I am aware of that local file need to remotely visible for playing so I have try some options: -

First One I open a android socket and write file into output stream of socket.

But it is not playable on DLNA device.
I think it is because android socket write row data into out put stream which DLNA renderer is not able to read.

Second I try with "https://github.com/julesbou/simple-framework"
simple framework, It also help to open socket

with it some times media will play on DLNA renderer but it not at every time.
and other problem with it is that it is not taking media item METADATA.

Please suggest some solution for the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can change file path to database id such as http://172_168.1.1:4566/id/5.
File path has the messy word problem in some device.